# How do these two results not conflict with each other?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis* by Zorich, at page 123, it is asked that

[image]

For **question 1(b)**, I can give the set 
$$A = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}| 0\leq x \leq 1\}.$$

and for **question 1(a)**, I have argued that if $I = \{I_i\}$ is an at most countable open cover for $E$, than $\bar E \subset \bar I$, and $\mu(\bar I_i) \leq \mu(I_i) + \mu(\partial I_i)$ and for any interval $I_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\partial I_i$ is has measure zero, hence $\bar E$ has to have measure zero.

**However,** how does these two results do not conflict with each other ?

**Edit:**

As it is pointed out in the comments by @Dap, $\mu$ represents the Jordan measure, so the problem has been solved thanks to the comments.

Comment: 1a) does not hold oin general.

Comment: The first statement is false. Take as $E$ any dense countable set.

Comment: What is $\mu$? ${}{}{}$

Comment: I'm thinking why the proof in the question 1 is wrong..

Comment: @ElfHog Good because after the given counterexamples, I was going to ask that :)

Comment: @JohnMa measure function.

Comment: I don't know what $\mu$ is but if it is Jordan content, then a indeed a Jordan-measurable set with Jordan content zero has a closure with content zero. @JohnMa

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\mu(E)$ denotes the measure (in the sense of Lebesgue )of the set $E$.

Comment: What kinds of measure? It can't be just any measure right?

Comment: @JohnMa You are right, see the last comment of mine.

Comment: Label $(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ with countable set.  Then consider $\{q_i\}_i=(0,1)\cap\mathbb{Q}$, we define $\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty (q_i-2^{i+2},q_i+2^{i+2})$.  From measure of this union, it must not cover $(0,1)$ but it seems to cover $(0,1)$??

Comment: @onurcanbektas I think the question is asking about Lebesgue measure as mentioned in tags

Comment: The previous sentence in the book (actually Mathematical Analysis II) is "That is the reason the measure $\mu(E)$ defined earlier can be called (and is called) the Jordan measure of the (Jordan-measurable) set $E.$"

Comment: Looking up the book on Google Books, **on exactly the same page 123**, Zorich defines $\mu$ as Jordan measure: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=q5KRCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=zorich+mathematical+analysis+jordan+measure&source=bl&ots=WJ52X0XnSF&sig=2ro3yxNHtgEAf1pOsa5plC5VJ4U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM_bvR2YbZAhWJLMAKHStmB8YQ6AEILzAC#v=onepage&q=zorich%20mathematical%20analysis%20jordan%20measure&f=false

Comment: @Dap You are right, I have missed that sentence. Thanks for pointing out. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: In fact it looks like the book never uses or defines Lebesgue measure, though it does define Lebesgue measure zero sets.

Comment: Then I guess the main problem is the finiteness of Jordan measure.  But still I feel weird about the $(0,1)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ example with conflict of measures of sets (of the union and $(0,1)$)

Comment: @Dap See the first page of __chapter 11__, it defines a measure for $\mathbb{R}^n$, which I understand that it is Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Can you add to your question the definitions of jordan measure and "lebesgue measure" given in the book?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: that's not Lebesgue measure

Comment: The question can be closed, because the problem stems from the fact that I  assumed $\mu$ as Lebesgue measure, and not Jordan measure.

Comment: @onurcanbektas You can delete your own question I suppose. I find no appropriate reasons to cast a close vote.

Comment: @awllower the book actually uses $\mu$ for measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ at the beginning of chapter 11, so I thought it might be useful for some other people who are also confused as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mathematical Analysis II" uses $\mu$ for Jordan measure, which is not defined for your set $A.$ And while the book defines Lebesgue measure zero sets, it never defines or uses Lebesgue measure.

To answer 1(a), use a **finite** cover $C_1,\dots,C_k$ of $E$ by $n$-dimensional closed intervals of total measure less than $\epsilon,$ and note that the closure of $E$ is also covered by the same set. (If Jordan measure is defined in terms of half-open intervals or whatever, you might need to enlarge them slightly while keeping the total measure less than $2\epsilon$ say.)

Your answer for 1(b) is correct, as long as you know why that set is a Lebesgue measure zero set.